# mongoose mongo.js save array with array to collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this "schema" in mongoose, an array in my dictionary and have other embedded array,

I can save if no embedded object is present, how to save embedded objects?

```
var ReportSchema   = new Schema({
    appVersion: { type: String, required: true},
    osVersion: { type: String, required: true},
    deviceType: { type: String, required: true},
    userID: { type: String, required: true},
    sessionIDtimestamp: { type: String, required: true},

    eventItem : [new Schema ({
        eventType:{type :String},
        startTime:{type :String},
        endTime:{type :String},
        params:[new Schema ({
            val:{type :String}
        })]
    })]
});
```

on my router:

```
apiRouter.route('/report') 
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var report = new Report();       

        report.appVersion = req.body.appVersion;   
        report.osVersion = req.body.osVersion;   
        report.deviceType = req.body.deviceType;    
        report.userID = req.body.userID;   
        report.sessionIDtimestamp = req.body.sessionIDtimestamp;   

        for (var i = req.body.events.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var requestStringa = util.inspect(req.body.events, {showHidden: false, depth: null});
            console.log("entro :"+requestStringa);      
        };

        report.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({ message: 'report created!' });
        });
    })
```

also i dont think that way to enumerate the array is nice?

edit
the log of events

```
entro :[ { eventType: 'Account_Rated_Pressed',
    startTime: '1435819399',
    endTime: '1435819399',
    params: [ { paramKey: 'rating', paramValue: '5' } ] },
  { eventType: 'RateableDetail',
    startTime: '1435819399',
    endTime: '1435819399',
    params: [ { paramKey: 'rating', paramValue: '5' } ] } ]
```

how to save my embedded objects cheers

Comment: Can you show us the data for `req.body.events`?

Comment: Since that's already an array, can't you just do `report.eventItem = req.body.events;`?

Comment: @chridam correct! thanks! post as answer to get the points, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving embedded documents, just assign the array field `eventItem` the request object value as follows:

```
apiRouter.route('/report') 
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var report = new Report();       

        report.appVersion = req.body.appVersion;   
        report.osVersion = req.body.osVersion;   
        report.deviceType = req.body.deviceType;    
        report.userID = req.body.userID;   
        report.sessionIDtimestamp = req.body.sessionIDtimestamp;   
        report.eventItem = req.body.events;

        report.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({ message: 'report created!' });
        });
    })
```

In the instance that `req.body.event` is an object not an array, you would then need to use the JavaScript **[`push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** method to push the object to the array. Say for example, if `req.body.event` has the structure

```
{ 
    eventType: 'Account_Rated_Pressed',
    startTime: '1435819399',
    endTime: '1435819399',
    params: [ { paramKey: 'rating', paramValue: '5' } ] 
}
```

you can then do

```
apiRouter.route('/report') 
    .post(function(req, res) {
        var report = new Report();       

        report.appVersion = req.body.appVersion;   
        report.osVersion = req.body.osVersion;   
        report.deviceType = req.body.deviceType;    
        report.userID = req.body.userID;   
        report.sessionIDtimestamp = req.body.sessionIDtimestamp;   
        report.eventItem.push(req.body.event);

        report.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                return res.send(err);
            }
            res.json({ message: 'report created!' });
        });
    })
```

Comment: thanks! is obvious now! wow nosql and new thinking! thanks a lot ;)

Comment: @MaKo No worries! I've also added some useful bits to the answer in the event that the `req.body.event` is an object not an array.